# Continue chatgpt api function call when is finishes due to length

Tags: typescript, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I am trying to call chatgpt using a function call and it responds with finish reason being the length of the tokens. So my questions is how to continue without messing the function_call results?

I am calling a function recursively when it finishes due to length.

Here is the code:

```
const chatJSONFunctionCall = async (messages: ChatCompletionMessageParam[],schema: any,lastChatReply: string): Promise<OpenAIApi.Chat.Completions.ChatCompletion> => {
    if(lastChatReply.length > 0){
        messages.push({ role: "assistant", content: lastChatReply })
    }
    
    try {
        const completionStream = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            messages: messages,
            model: "gpt-4",
            max_tokens: 100,
            // n: 3,
            stop: null,
            temperature: 0.5,
            functions: [{ name: "respond_in_json", parameters: schema }],
            function_call: { name:"respond_in_json" }
        });

        return completionStream;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        throw new Error("Error in connection")
    }
}

const translate = async (targetLang: string, textObj: any): Promise<any> => {

    const schema = generateFunctionCallSchema(textObj)

    const source_language = "English";

    const prompt = `Translate and rephrase the following ${source_language} JSON to ${targetLang} and try to be sexy. Given JSON: ${JSON.stringify(textObj)}`;

    const messages: ChatCompletionMessageParam[] = [
        { "role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant that translates and rephrases JSON values based on your user's given JSON. Be sure to only change the values of the JSON and not the keys" },
        { "role": "user", "content": prompt }
    ]
    let content: string = ""
    let lastChatReply: string = ""
    const translateRecurr = async (messages: ChatCompletionMessageParam[]): Promise<any> => {
        console.log(messages);
        
        try {
            const completion = await chatJSONFunctionCall(messages,schema,lastChatReply);
            console.log(completion);
            
            const finishReason = completion.choices[0].finish_reason;
            console.log(finishReason);
            
            if (finishReason == "length") {
                content = content + completion.choices[0].message.content
                if(completion.choices[0].message.function_call?.arguments){
                    lastChatReply = completion.choices[0].message.function_call?.arguments
                }
                return await translateRecurr(messages)
            }
            if (finishReason === "stop") {
                content = content + completion.choices[0].message.content
                const result = JSON.parse(content);
                return result

            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
  }
    return await translateRecurr(messages);
}
```

I was expecting to continue the response in json but it just gives back a new json in response that never seems to finish.

This is the conversation

```
[
  {
    role: "system",
    content: "You are a helpful assistant that translates and rephrases JSON values based on your user's given JSON. Be sure to only change the values of the JSON and not the keys"
  },
  {
    role: "user",
    content: "Translate and rephrase the following English JSON to greek and try to be sexy. Given JSON: {\"backTask\":\"Back to task Yeah\",\"continue\":\"Continue\",\"giveUp\":\"Give up\",\"goBack\":\"Go back\",\"okGotIt\":\"Ok. Got it!\",\"skipQuestion\":\"Skip this question\",\"skipTask\":\"Skip task\",\"pinTask\":\"Pin task\",\"justSkip\":\"Skip\",\"preview\":\"This is a preview of your test, we won't collect any data.\"}"
  },
  {
    role: "assistant",
    content: "{\n  \"backTask\": \"Επιστροφή στην εργασία. Ω ναι!\",\n  \"continue\": \"Συνέχισε\",\n  \"giveUp\": \"Παράτα το\",\n  \"goBack\": \"Πήγαινε πίσω\",\n  \"okGotIt\": \"Εντάξει."
  },
  {
    role: "user",
    content: "continue generating"
  }, {
    role: "assistant",
    content: "{\n  \"okGotIt\": \"Εντάξει. Το έπιασα!\",\n  \"skipQuestion\": \"Παράλειψε αυτή την ερώτηση\",\n  \"skipTask\": \"Παράλειψε την εργασία\",\n  \"pinTask\": \"Καρ"
  },
  {
    role: "user",
    content: "continue generating"
  }, {
    role: "assistant",
    content: "{\n  \"pinTask\": \"Καρφίτσωσε την εργασία\",\n  \"justSkip\": \"Απλά παράλειψε\",\n  \"preview\": \"Αυτή είναι μια προεπισκόπηση του τεστ σου, δεν θα συλλ"
  },
  {
    role: "user",
    content: "continue generating"
  }
]
```

Does anybody has any idea how to handle the function call response so I get a complete json no matter the length. Thank you

Comment: Hey, there are lots of part of this question which I would love some clarification on, what is the finish reason you are getting? Is it "length"? Is that the issue you are trying to resolve? Or are you trying to see how you can avoid getting "length" as the finish reason?